# Integrate PHP page in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I need to integrate a PHP page in an ASP.NET MVC4 application, so that i can render that page in the view.

I have referred this link.
http://forums.asp.net/t/1853162.aspx?Integrating+PHP+pages+into+ASP+NET+MVC+3+appication+and+deploying+on+IIS+7

and included the php page in the application. However not sure about the further steps.

Answer (score 1):

Rupesh can you just request the php page with webclient from a controller and render the resulting html in an mvc view?

```
    public ActionResult displayPHPPage(string url)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            string response =  client.DownloadString(url);
            return View(response);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do i include the php page in my mvc project and then call it directly from there, instead of calling a url where the php page is being hosted.

Comment: I don't think the MVC view engine supports serving .php files even if your web server has php on it. I found this but it looks old. https://phpviewengine.codeplex.com/